# Science Fiction Novel with two Androids on a "New Earth" planet; named The Admiral and The Sergeant

Tags: story-identification, novel

I am looking for the name and author of a book series I read in the 1980's about several earth like federations (including a south american federation that was Brazilian) having to leave a dying planet in spacecraft to a new planet to colonize. I think it had earth in the title and possibly the year like 2020 or 2200. I don't specifically recall.

I do remember the first wave of of travelers included military personal and scientists. In the first novel there was a military android named 'The Admiral' with AI and kinds of offensive/defensive capabilities. Later in the second or third novel in the series there was another version of 'The Admiral' named 'The Sergeant' who was more militaristic and had more capabilities.

Thanks for anyone who can name the author or the book series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be "[America 2040](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/055325541X)" by Evan Innes (a pen-name of Hugh Zachary).

> In the year 2033, the American president is given an ultimatum by his
>   mad Russian counterpart: Let the Soviets take over the world or it
>   will be destoyed. The president orders a spaceship built so that
>   Americans can colonize a far-distant planet. War breaks out as the
>   vessel lifts off, and communications are conveniently sabotaged so the
>   fate of Earth is never known. High melodrama ensues on the ship,
>   culminating in the righteous Americanization of a pristine planet.

Chapter 11 contains the quote:

> "*The military defense android called The Admiral had abandoned his
>   medal-bedecked uniform*"

And the book's wikipedia page mentions the other android; [The Sergeant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America_2040#The_Sergeant)

> A robot more handsome, powerful and intelligent than a man, he has
>   inexplicably begun to be human in his dangerous jealousy to the
>   Admiral...The Fellow robot he becomes obsessed to kill.

Comment: For the record, this book looks dreadful.